# Replace background image with CSS gradient

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I use an image for the background of a fixed-width div with id `header`, the relevant CSS rule is

```
#header {
  background: url("bg.png") no-repeat scroll center top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I'm trying to make this page more responsive, which means that the width of `header` is now variable. In the unresponsive page the `header` element was always the same width as the background image, but in the responsive design the element could be wider or narrower than the image. I need to use the same background style in the responsive page, but I can't find a way to do this when the size of the element and image don't match.

Comment: Try using [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). It should help in your case.

Comment: Have you tried `background-size:cover;` or `contain`? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Comment: This is a great resource for generating CSS background gradients, if you choose to move away from using images: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider

```
background: url("bg.png") repeat-y top left;
background-size: cover;
```

[W3schools has more info on the background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

EDIT:
[Since that W3Schools seems a form of heresy, here is another reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: your answer is correct but please use mdn for reference. w3schools is not recommended by many senior developers. specially here. (_I am not the downvoter_)

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on the -1?

Comment: I specifically chose w3schools because it offers an easy way to test multiple background-size options. Given the nature of this question, that might be what the Dónal is looking for.